# Sending E-mail When Sessions timestamp is 90 min old

Tags: php, mysql, email, triggers

I have a mysql db that gets populated with the session info below called my_active_users

```
username    timestamp      email
MyName      1351121630     xxx@xxx.com
```

How can I send up a trigger to send a e-mail to the user when the session timestamp is over 90 min old?

I already have the mail.php set up to send the e-mail with the proper content just not sure how I would link or trigger the mail to be sent to the users who have not been active for 90 min.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set up a cron job that sends the emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @nickb,

Write a script (pseudo-code here):

```
SELECT user, firstname, lastname, email
from sometable 
where timestamp > (current_time - 90mins)
```

Then personalise and send using your *`mail.php`* script.

Where the crontab is concerned, I don't know how much you know about it, but, you can either execute it via PHP or a service like wget (or lynx etc):

**PHP:**

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script/script.php
```

**Or via URL request:**

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O http://www.domain.com/script.php > /dev/null
```

Both of the above request every 10 minutes, but you can change to fit your requirements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: when setting up the cron job should i use GET /usr/bin/GET http://www.some-domain.com/file.php or the normal: php /home/user_name123/public_html/sessionmail.php ?

Comment: Ahh, no, define your script, include mail.php and execute it using the crontab - the latter: (php /home/etc../sessionmail.php). Will update my answer if needs be!

Comment: In the command field when creating the cron job I assume I just call the location of the send mail file after choosing the times/dates one way is using the GET command and the other is using the php5 command

Comment: Your next conundrum is 'how often' should you run your cron script! ;)